# How to run the example of ViewPager on Android developer site?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager

When I try to run the example with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html on Eclipse,the emulator was display a error dialog .

Here is the LogCat:
[image]

I just don't know why it can't run.I build the project and copy the example code in Eclipse,I also set the Android API level with 11.And it seem all is ok.

When I double click the last but one line of the LogCat:

```
at com.lanz.xbp2v4.ActionBarTabsPage.onCreate.java:37
```

it redirect to the code which included in onCreate method :

```
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

So I think it may something wrong in this part of code,hope that someone can help me!XD

the code in onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(mViewPager);
        // Full Screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();         
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);     
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE); 

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Simple").setTabListener((TabListener) this),
                IndexTab.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("List").setTabListener((TabListener) this),
                Tab2.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Cursor").setTabListener((TabListener) this),
                Tab3.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        }
    }
```

---

I has fixed the problem above,but it still can't work.At this time I run the example app,the LogCat show:
[image]

it redirect to the code which included in `getItem()` method :

```
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            Fragment fragment=Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
            return fragment;
        }
```

Is anyone can run the example code with [Android developer ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)?

Comment: Seems like your ActionBar object is null, are you sure it is being initialised?

Comment: Your app extends and you call `this.getActionBar()`. Simply `Log()` the bar.toString() to see if its a null.

Comment: I post the onCreate method code

Answer (score 0):

your `getActionBar()` is returning null.

From this [link](http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html), you need to make the window title visible for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I fixed this problem,but the example app still can't work,it seem the `public Fragment getItem(int position)` have problem.